# Get the dd-MM-yyyy format of date in Java (JSP)

Tags: java, date, date-format, simpledateformat

I'm using an input=date calendar, and i want to output this format of date (dd-MM-yyyy) in my jsp ,when i choose the 2nd day of april 2014 in the calendar given by the input ,I have this output in my jsp:

Wed Apr 02 00:00:00 WET 2014

Here you are the code:

**index.jsp** :

```xml
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form name="datepickeer" action="showdates.jsp" method="POST">
            <table>
                <tr><td>Date début :</td> <td><input type = "date" name = "datedebut">
                    </td><tr>
                <tr><td><input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "submit">
                    </td></tr>
            </table>
        </form>
    </body>
</html>
```

**showdates.jsp** :

```xml
<%@ page import="java.util.Date,java.text.SimpleDateFormat,java.text.ParseException"%>
<%@page import="java.text.SimpleDateFormat"%>
<%@page contentType="text/html" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>JSP Page</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <% String dateStr = request.getParameter("datedebut");
            SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
            Date result = formater.parse(dateStr);
            out.println(result);
        %>
    </body>
</html>
```

What's the problem with my code?

Comment: Please do as [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/22983439/1391249) answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
String dateStr = request.getParameter("datedebut");
  SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
  Date result = formater.parse(dateStr);
  SimpleDateFormat AppDateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
  out.println(AppDateFormat.format(result));
```

Comment: Stack Overflow is a Q&A site wherein everyone upvotes each other upon agreement. Stack Overflow is not an old fashioned discussion forum wherein everyone repeats each other into an undigestable mess upon agreement.

Answer (score 5):

Try this -

```
<% 
     String dateStr = request.getParameter("datedebut");
     SimpleDateFormat formater = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
     Date result = formater.parse(dateStr);
     SimpleDateFormat newFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
     out.println(newFormater.format(result));
%>
```

Comment: @Subharajyoti Majumde : I tried it and the output is : 2014-04-02 instead of the format i want : 02-04-2014

Comment: Opps.... In that case - create new Formatter `new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");` and format the parsed date

Comment: @Subharajyoti Majumde : I did this:    <%String dateStr = request.getParameter("datedebut");  
    SimpleDateFormat formater2= new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
    Date result = formater2.parse(dateStr);
    out.println(result);%> ,I choose the second of april 2014 and I got this output: Wed Oct 05 00:00:00 WET 7

Comment: thank you so muuuuuuch you just save my life yeey wish u all the best

Answer (score 0):

You have converted the input from index.jsp into Date using formater.parse. Now to show it on the output in showdates.jsp, you have to again convert into String using formater.format(result) to yyyy-MM-dd.  Actually what you are doing is correct. Whatever you get from input you should first parse and then print because you will be sure that the input which came fits into what you require.  Use this.

```
Date result = formater.parse(dateStr);
SimpleDateFormat formaterForOut = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-MM-yyyy");
String resultString = formaterForOut.format(result); 
out.println(resultString);
```

Comment: I tried your code and I got the same output : 
Wed Apr 02 00:00:00 WET 2014

Answer (score 0):

```
<% 

  String dateStr = request.getParameter("datedebut");

  java.text.SimpleDateFormat oldFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
  java.util.Date resultInDate = oldFormater.parse(dateStr);

  java.text.SimpleDateFormat newFormater = new SimpleDateFormat("dd-mm-yyyy");
  String resultInString = newFormater.format(resultInDate);

  out.println(resultInDate); // Wed Apr 02 00:00:00 WET 2014
  out.println(resultInString); // 02-04-2014

  /* convert String resultInString into java.sql.Date resultInDateSql */
  java.sql.Date resultInDateSql = java.sql.Date.valueOf(resultInString);

  /* set in query sql */
  preparedStatement.setDate(1, resultInDateSql);

%>
```